# 2d Schrodinger Equation via matrix diagonalization in C

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues, eigensystem, c, quantum-mechanics

I am trying to solve the time-independent Schrodinger equation in two dimensions via discrete matrix diagonalization.  I want the energy eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenfunctions for a given potential.

Eventually I want the solutions for the following potential (although as shown later I can't seem to get it working for any potential):
$$V(x,y) = x^{4} + y^{4}$$

To discretize the problem I use the following basis functions:
$$
\phi_{i}(x,y) =
\begin{cases} \frac{1}{h^{2}} & \frac{-h}{2}\leq x-x_{i}<\frac{h}{2}, \frac{-h}{2}\leq y-y_{i}<\frac{h}{2} \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
Essentially, each function occupies a single grid square with a normalized height of $\frac{1}{h^{2}}$ where $h$ is the width of a square.  This is a good basis to use because if I can find the eigenvectors expressed in this basis, it should be trivial to plot them.  To map the single index $i$ to the 2d grid I use the following scheme:

$$
x_{i} = h((i\mod N) - R) \\
y_{i} = h\left(\left\lfloor\frac{i}{N}\right\rfloor - R\right) \\
N = 2R + 1
$$
where `R` is an integer 'radius'.  This is to say the domain is an $N\times N$ grid centered at the origin.  The ordering starts at $(-R,-R)$ and reads until $(R,-R)$ before advancing to the above row at $(-R,-R+1)$ and so on and so forth.

The matrix for the kinetic term of the Hamiltonian will be constructed from the Laplacian matrix operator. I use 
$$
\nabla^{2} =
\begin{pmatrix}
-4 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & -4 & 1 & \ddots & \ddots \\
0 & 1 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 1\\
1 & \ddots  & \ddots & \ddots & 1 & 0  \\
& \ddots & \ddots  & 1  & -4& 0  \\ 
& & 1 &  0  & 0 & -4   \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Each row in the grid domain is punctuated by zeros on the sub and super-diagonals, then the pattern repeats.  The potential matrix is diagonal given by
$$V_{ij} = \delta_{ij} \langle i | V | j\rangle$$

Thus the matrix Hamiltonian:
$$
\mathbf{H} = -\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\nabla^{2} + \mathbf{V}
$$

Currently, $\mathbf{H}$ is not tridiagonal. So first I use Numerical Recipe's `tred2` routine.  This outputs the diagonal terms into a 1d array and the off-diagonals into another array.  I then pass these two arrays into Numerical Recipe's `tqli` routine for the diagonalization.  This routine outputs the eigenvalues by overwriting the diagonal array (`d[k]` for $k$-th eigenvalue) and outputs the full set of eigenvectors as columns into a 2d array.

The output I am getting now is completely nonsensical.  My understanding was that the output array would have eigenvectors expressed in the original basis, so that I could visualize them via a heat map or the like with gnuplot. Am I missing a step, or is my code just erroneous?

Earlier I accidentally got it working for the 1d case.  I was using the wrong kinetic matrix (1d case is already tridiagonal) but with the 2d potential and some of the eigenvectors I saw actually resembled realistic wavefunctions.  So, if I didn't touch `tqli` since then then the problem isn't there.

Since I am unsure of what or where the problem is, I am going to provide the full program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//L is the unit width of the domain.
//R is the integer radius.  Number of states is (1+2R)^2
//m is particle mass. 
#define L 2.0
#define R 15
#define m 1.0

double V(int,double);
double x(int,double);
double y(int,double);
void tred2(double**,int,double*,double*);
void tqli(double*,double*,int,double**);
double pythag(double a,double b);

double x(int i,double h) {return h*((i%(1+2*R) - R));}
double y(int i,double h) {return h*(i/(1+2*R) - R);}

//potential function. returns the integral over the grid square indexed by i
double V(int i,double h) {
double xi=pow(x(i,h),2),yi=pow(y(i,h),2),v;
v = pow(h,5)/40.0;
v += h*h*(xi*xi+yi*yi)/2.0;
v += pow(xi,4) + pow(yi,4);
return v;}


double pythag(double a, double b) {
double A=fabs(a),B=fabs(b);
if (A>B) {return A*sqrt(1.0+pow(B/A,2));}
return (B==0.0?0.0:B*sqrt(1.0+pow(A/B,2)));
}

void tred2(double **a,int n,double *d,double *e) {
  int l,k,j,i;
  double scale,hh,h,g,f;

  for (i=n-1;i>0;i--) {
    l = i - 1;
    h = scale = 0.0;
    if (l>0) {
      for (k=0;k<=l;k++) {scale += fabs(a[i][k]);}
      if (scale==0.0) {e[i] = a[i][l];}
      else {
        for (k=0;k<=l;k++) {
          a[i][k] /= scale;
          h += a[i][k]*a[i][k];
        }
        f = a[i][l];
        g = (f>=0.0?-sqrt(h):sqrt(h));
        e[i]=scale*g;
        h -= f*g;
        a[i][l] = f-g;
        f = 0.0;
        for (j=0;j<=l;j++) {
          a[j][i] = a[i][j]/h;
          g = 0.0;
          for (k=0;k<=j;k++) {g += a[j][k]*a[i][k];}
          for (k=j+1;k<=l;k++) {g += a[k][j]*a[i][k];}
      }
    }
    d[i] = a[i][i];
    a[i][i] = 1.0;
    for (j=0;j<=l;j++) {a[j][i] = a[i][j] = 0.0;}
  }
}

void tqli(double *d,double *e,int n,double **z) {
  int j,l,it,i,k;
  double s,r,p,g,f,dd,c,b;

  for (i=2;i<n;i++) {e[i-1] = e[i];}
  e[n-1] = 0.0;
  for (l=0;l<n;l++) {
    it = 0;
    do {
      for (j=l;j<n-1;j++) {
        dd = fabs(d[j])+fabs(d[j+1]);
        if ((double)(fabs(e[j])+dd) == dd) break;
      }
      if (j!=l) {
        if (it++ == 30) {printf("Too many iterations in tqli\n");}
        g = (d[l+1]-d[l])/(2.0*e[l]);
        r = pythag(g,1.0);
        g = d[j]-d[l]+e[l]/(g+(g<0.0)?-r:r);
        s = c = 1.0;
        p = 0.0;
        for (i=j-1;i>=l;i--) {
          f = s*e[i];
          b = c*e[i];
          r = pythag(f,g);
          e[i+1] = r;
          if (r == 0.0) {
            d[i+1] -= p;
            e[j] = 0.0;
            break;
          }
          s = f/r;
          c = g/r;
          g = d[i+1] - p;
          r = (d[i]-g)*s + 2.0*c*b;
          d[i+1] = g + (p = s*r);
          g = c*r - b;
          for (k=0;k<n;k++) {
            f = z[k][i+1];
            z[k][i+1] = s*z[k][i] + c*f;
            z[k][i] = c*z[k][i] - s*f;
          }
        }
        if (r == 0.0 && i >= l) continue;
        d[l] -= p;
        e[l] = g;
        e[j] = 0.0;
      }
    } while (j != l);
  }
}

void main() {
int i,j,N=1+2*R,M,a=0;
double **H,h=L/N,dd,*D,*T,q;
FILE *f;
dd = pow(h,-2);
M = N*N; //M is total number of states

D = (double *) malloc(M*sizeof(double));
T = (double *) malloc(M*sizeof(double));
H = (double **) malloc(M*sizeof(double*));
H[0] = (double *) malloc(M*M*sizeof(double));
for (i=1;i<M;i++) {
H[i] = H[i-1] + M;
}

//initialize Hamiltonian in discrete basis.  triangular loop by symmetry.
for (i=0;i<M;i++) {
  *(H[i]+i) = V(i,h) + 2*dd/m;
  for (j=i+1;j<M;j++) {
    *(H[i]+j) = 0.0;
    if (j==i+1 && i%N!=N-1) {*(H[i]+j) = -dd/2;}
    else if (j==i+3) {*(H[i]+j) = -dd/2;}
    *(H[j]+i) = *(H[i]+j);
  }
}

//D and T are empty, but tred2 will write into them. D for diagonals, T for the off-diagonal terms
tred2(H,M,D,T);
//tred2 outputs H as the identity matrix, which will be fed into tqli for the eigenvectors
tqli(D,T,M,H);
//D[k] now contains kth eigenvalue.  H columns are eigenvectors
//you may decide how you want to visualize the output
}
```

The original routines can be found in the eigensystems section in http://www2.geog.ucl.ac.uk/~mdisney/teaching/GEOGG121/inversion/NumericalRecipesinC.pdf
Note:  they use arrays of `a[1...n]` so I converted the functions so they would work on `a[0...n-1]` indexed arrays.

I have tried many different values for size and $h$ but all the output is garbage.  A typical output is zero in most places but with completely random valued stripes or spots without any kind of symmetry.

Comment: If its about solving the TDSE for this particular potential, this can be better done in radial coordinates. You should then be able ro treat the angular part analytically.

Comment: @davidhigh, Ah, that might help for verifying the solutions, but I need to solve this problem numerically, specifically through matrix diagonalization..  Besides, if I can get this to work it will also work with any arbitrary potential.

Comment: Just a comment: Do you insist to solve it in this way for probably educational purposes or you have some freedom to choose whatever works for you? I think there are lots of more straightforward ways to do this.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer  Educational purposes.

Answer (score 3):

1. Test your code. "I don't know if my linear algebra routines work or not" is a problem you can solve easily. It is easy to check if you have computed the correct eigenvalues or not; just check that $VDV^{-1}=H$, or if you don't fancy the inversion $HV=VD$. If you are not sure that your individual pieces work, you are walking in the dark.
2. Possibly a hot take: use a different language. With C all code takes longer to write (and read) with respect to a language that has more numerical libraries and some more syntactic sugar for faster developing/prototyping. You are not even sure if your discretization strategy is sound here; it is not the time to use the fastest-language-in-the-world for performance reasons. Just do your early development and debugging in a friendlier environment. Chances are that you won't even need to move to C for performance reasons in this problem, since 90% of your CPU time will be spent in a linear algebra library anyway.

Comment: I already know it doesn't work.  I stumped as to why.

Answer (score 1):

Your whole code is not understandable to me. Try this alternative components:

```
int grid(int i, double a, double h)
{
    return a+i*h;
}

int index(int i, int j, int N)
{
    return i*N+j;
}

//potential function. returns the integral over the grid square indexed by i
double V(int i, double x0, double hx, int j, double y0, double hy)
{
    double xi=grid(i,x0,hx);
    double yi=grid(j,y0,hy);
    return pow(xi,4) + pow(yi,4);
}
```

Then use the following code to initialize your Hamiltonian:

```
//initialize Hamiltonian in discrete basis.  no triangular loop at first!
int M2=M*M;
//set Hamiltonian to zero
for (i=0;i<M;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<M;j++)
    {
         H((i*M+i)*M2+(j*M+j)) = -2.0/(hx*hx) - 2.0/(hy*hy) + V(i,x0,hx,j,y0,hx);
         H((i*M+(i+1))*M2+(j*M+j)) = 1.0/(hx*hx);
         H((i*M+(i-1))*M2+(j*M+j)) = 1.0/(hx*hx);
         H((i*M+i)*M2+(j*M+(j+1))) = 1.0/(hy*hy);
         H((i*M+i))*M2+(j*M+(j-1))) = 1.0/(hy*hy);
    }
}
```

Note that this code will probably not run, because I'm not a C guy. but it should give you the idea. Notably, it's not necessary to do the modulo-and-integer-division index hackery.

Comment: The grid is not the problem.  I have tested that part and it returns what I want, something is happening down the line in either ```tred2``` or ```tlqi```.